# Foreach in JS with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get a JSON Object from my PHP:

```
{
"Data":{
       "Recipes":{
                    "Recipe_7":{
                                 "ID":"7",
                                 "TITLE":"Wurstel"
                               },
                    "Recipe_43":{
                                  "ID":"43",
                                  "TITLE":"Wurstel2"
                                 }
                 }
        },
"Message":null,
"Code":200
}
```

and i want to parse it in `JS` to get the `id` and the `title`

My Code:

```
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);

 $.each(obj, function(){

 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.recipes.toString();
 });
```

The problem is that i always get UNDEFINED

My Quest:

How to parse the obj to get the `titel` and the `id` of each Recipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj;

try {
    obj = jQuery.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
} catch (e) {
   // Invalid JSON
}

if (obj) {
    var recipes = obj.Data.Recipes;

    for (var x in recipes) {
        // recipes[x].ID
        // recipes[x].TITLE
    }
}
```

As you're already using the jQuery library, you might want to look at using the [AJAX module](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax) in jQuery. It stops you worrying about the browser differences (`XMLHttpRequest` vs `ActiveX`) etc.

You can then use the [`.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method, and you'll receive a parsed response for you, making things slightly easier:

```
jQuery.getJSON('yourUrl.php', function (obj) {  // obj is now a JS object
    var recipes = obj.Data.Recipes;

    for (var x in recipes) {
        // recipes[x].ID
        // recipes[x].TITLE
    }        
});
```

If you're adament you want to use jQuery.each, replace:

```
var recipes = obj.Data.Recipes;

for (var x in recipes) {
    // recipes[x].ID
    // recipes[x].TITLE
}
```

with:

```
jQuery.each(obj.Data.Recipes, function () {
    // this.ID
    // this.TITLE
});
```

**Be vary aware that JavaScript is case sensitive; `DATA !== Data` and `ID != id`.**

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);

// assign outside of loop.
var str = "";

// append to str variable each iteration
$.each(obj.Data.Recipes,function(){
   str += this.ID + "<br />";
   str += this.TITLE + "<br />";
});

// moved outside of loop, because innerHTML would've been overwritten every iteration.
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `each` method like this

```
$.each(obj.Data.Recipes, function(i, item){
    // get each Recipe via the item variable. like item.ID or item.TITLE        
});
```

However, when you are inside the loop, your `innerHTML =` would not work as you would only ever display the last recipe.

You would want to build up a string based on the `item.TITLE` then assign this to the `innerHTML` of `txtHint`. As you are using jQuery you can just use `$('#txtHint').html(value);`